# Selecting image on ClickEvent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need some help in JavaScript, HTML, HTML DOM and DHTML. I am not too familiar with JavaScript but I am trying to create website using JavaScript and HTML. Here is the situation:

```
div                          div
main image                   main image

image1                       image1
image2                       image2
image3                       image3 
                             image4
```

By default it will show up image1 as main image on Page load and when user click on any image under that div it should replace main image.

```
function ChangesSrc()
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        x = 1;
        document.getElementById('image1').src = "";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.width = "306px";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.height = "230px";   
    }
    else if(x == 1)
    {
        x = 2;
        document.getElementById('image1').src = "";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.width = "306px";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.height = "230px";       
    }
    else if(x == 2)
    {
        x = 0;
        document.getElementById('image1').src = "";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.width = "306px";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.height = "230px";           
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
        document.getElementById('image1').src = "";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.width = "306px";
        document.getElementById('image1').style.height = "230px";       
    }
            
}
</script>
```

My problem is I do have to specify image src for each and every image on click event and also it display images in sequence (if I am clicking on last image first; still it shows first image as main image only).

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: That's a lot of repetition that should be condensed into just a few lines. Also, if you attach an event instead of add one with `onclick=""` markup attributes, you can actually access the `img` (or otherwise) element you clicked on inside the handler (function). You would do this with `this.src`, `this.style.height`, etc.

Comment: that's the point - i want to know how to do that

Comment: x : I am assuming as click and on each click event image will changes

Comment: @DavidThomas - I think it's [Greek in origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X). Here in this question, not so much.

Comment: Rushabh, so you want to have a picture at the top of a list of pictures, and when someone clicks on one of the lower pictures, it swaps with the main image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function openimage(mainimageurl)
{

        document.getElementById('Idofthebimage').src =mainimageurl;
        //set the width height once in css  

 }
```

now say on every image write this `onclick="openimage(this.src)"` or if bigger image url is different `onclick="openimage('theurlofthebiggerimage')"`

Comment: function did work but it will show up only one image at a time if I want to show up second image I need to reload the page

Comment: ok answer me. say there are three small images and one big image. when you click on a small image, you want that image to be shown as bg replacing the current big image right?

Comment: then read my answer, it explains the steps. have a click event on every image

Comment: If you use an event handler, ie `img.onclick` or `addEventListener()`, you don't have to pass element information like `this.src` in the inline handler. That's because inside the handler, `this` corresponds to the element for which the event was fired by.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following, though it may lack some of your particulars, since I've used CSS to style the smaller images (`.thumbs`) and the main image (`#main`):

```
function show(el) {
    if (!el) {
        // function requires a reference to the clicked element, here 'el'
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // finds the element with id="main"
        var showIn = document.getElementById('main'),
            // sets the sISrc variable with the src of the showIn element
            sISrc = showIn.src,
            // sets the variable 'elSrc' with the src value of the clicked element
            elSrc = el.src;
        // re-sets the src of the 'main' element with the src of the clicked element
        showIn.src = elSrc;
        // sets the clicked element's src to the (previous) value of the 'main' element
        el.src = sISrc;
    }
}

// finds all the images
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
    // iterates through all the images and assigns an 'onclick' event-handler
    images[i].onclick = function() {
        // passes the current image into the show() function when clicked
        show(this);
    };
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LwQwd/).

---

**Edited** above code revised to allow for multiple instances of the...gallery thing, this version will only affect the `.main` element (as there are, or may be, multiple elements with the same identifier I've switched to `class` names, though in the current version this requires that the images are within the same (immediate) parent (`el.parentNode`):

```
function show(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var showIn = el.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('main')[0],
            sISrc = showIn.src,
            elSrc = el.src;
        showIn.src = elSrc;
        el.src = sISrc;
    }
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function() {
        show(this);
    };
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LwQwd/1/).

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: You had the same basic idea I had, except why don't you do `images[i].onclick = show;`? Shorter, sweeter, no arguments over arguments.

Comment: Oh cool, so you swapped them too instead of pushing the out-swapped to the bottom or whatnot. I wasn't sure what the OP was after.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: to your first comment, I honestly didn't think to do it that way, though I like to be fairly explicit in the way I call/pass-to functions. In response to your second, I, too, was unsure as to what exactly the OP wanted; but this way *felt* right, and, from what I read of his question and comments, seemed closer to what I'd do myself.

Comment: At some point I got out of the habit of doing that, and now it just looks... funky. Doesn't matter either way I guess, just wondering if there was a reason I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I put together the following demo which shows how you can have a series of image elements and swap them with a main one at the top of the group.

I have included the `window.onload` event handler, as well, since you cannot attach element event handlers until that element has been parsed and added to the DOM, which (in most cases) helps to prevent errors occurring from within your Javascript.

This isn't the only way to handle the problems associated with running scripts before or during page loads (for instance, the script call run inline and access elements that have already been parsed *before* `window.onload` fires). But it is a common, mostly durable solution for smaller, more procedural scripts.

```
<div id="imgs">
    <div>
        <img id="mainimg" src="http://goo.gl/UohAz"/>
    </div>
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f893555be713a24dee52230712cdde3a?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/495d675e3bc42ed1dee469e2ce701f1b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/db5a61382c2ba7309071c323edb4013b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
</div>

window.onload = function() {
    var imgs = document.getElementById('imgs').getElementsByTagName('img'),
        mainimg = document.getElementById('mainimg'),
        i = imgs.length,
        lastimg;

    var swap = function() {
        var old = mainimg.src;

        mainimg.src = this.src;
        this.src = old;
    };

    while (i--) {
        img = imgs[i];
        img.id = 'img-' + i;

        if (img.parentNode.id == 'main-img') {
            lastimg = img.id;
        }

        img.onclick = swap;
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/yq9Fq/